# How to change non managed object to managed object in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have non managed objects data and I want to change those to managed object but it is not working.
I have three Following Entities or tables in core data

- Product
- Comment
- Brands

Product is main table, Comment is connected to Product with One to Many relationship(1 product has many comments), Brand is also connected to Product with One to One relationship.
I am fetching data from server side and write those data into these entities, by converting non managed to managed object. 
My Product related data write successfully but comments and Brand couldn't. Here below is my code. Product has Entity SCProduct and Comment has SCComment

in SCProduct.m

```
-(void)updateWithNMProduct:(NMProduct *)nmProduct{

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

self.costPrice = [nmProduct.costPrice copy];
self.coverPhoto = [nmProduct.coverPhoto copy];
self.coverPhotoNoSize = [nmProduct.coverPhotoUrlNoSize copy];
self.coverPhotoUrl = [nmProduct.coverPhotoUrl copy];
self.coverPhotoUrlEmail = [nmProduct.coverPhotoUrlEmail copy];
self.createdAt = [nmProduct.createdAt copy];
self.deliveryDays = [nmProduct.deliveryDays copy];
self.deliveryFee = [nmProduct.deliveryFee copy];
self.desc = [nmProduct.desc copy];
self.gender = [nmProduct.gender copy];
self.liked = [nmProduct.liked copy];
self.updatedAt = [nmProduct.updatedAt copy];
self.name = [nmProduct.name copy];
self.numberOfComments = [nmProduct.numberOfComments copy];
self.promoted = nmProduct.promoted;
self.salePrice = [nmProduct.salePrice copy];
self.taxRate = [nmProduct.taxRate copy];


//comments
[self.comments bk_each:^(SCComment *comment){
    [context deleteObject:comment];
}];


NSMutableOrderedSet* tempSequence = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:self.comments];
[tempSequence removeAllObjects];
self.comments = tempSequence;


for(NMComment *comment in nmProduct.comments){
    SCComment *managedComment = [SCComment findOrCreate:comment.commentId];
    [managedComment updateWithNonManagedData:comment];
    [self addItem:managedComment toSet:self.comments];
}
 NMBrand * brand = nmProduct.brand;
    SCBrand *managedComment = [SCBrand findOrCreate:[NSString           stringWithFormat:@"%@",brand.brandId]];
    [managedComment updateWithNonManagedData:managedComment];}
```

In SCComment.m

```
-(void)updateWithNonManagedData:(NMComment *)nmComment{

self.commentId = [nmComment.commentId copy];
self.key = [nmComment.key copy];

SCCommentValue *cValue = [SCCommentValue findOrCreate:nmComment.value.commentValueId];
[cValue updateWithNonManagedData:nmComment.value];
self.value = cValue;

SCCreator *creator = [SCCreator findOrCreate:nmComment.creator.creatorId];
[creator updateWithNonManagedData:nmComment.creator];
self.creator = creator;   }
```

I am able to get product's data fine but not comment. Relationship is fine and worked with managed object. Kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get any errors? Are you running that code on main thread? where are you inserting NSManagedObjects in your context?

Comment: No, there is no error, and yes already doing all work in main thread fetching from server and writing on DB. I am Inserting at the end by calling this method "saveToPersistentStore", Product is saving but comments are not. I think may the issue is in  for(NMComment *comment in nmProduct.comments){
        SCComment *managedComment = [SCComment findOrCreate:comment.commentId];
        [managedComment updateWithNonManagedData:comment];
        [self addItem:managedComment toSet:self.comments];
    }

Comment: From your post it is not obvious how you insert objects into the managedObjectContext... findOrCreate is not a standard NSManagedObject method, but your custom one. The same accounts for your other methods. So if one of these has a problem, how should anyone tell?

Comment: Can you please suggest me that how can we add values in NSOrder types object. And if same situation you have like product and comments how with 1 to many, how you are going to add values into comments?

Comment: I am not sure what you ask ... that is all covered ind entail in Apples CoreData documentation ... I suggest you read there. Without any knowledge of how your classes have all their methods implemented, there is no way of helping you with your problem that may be located somewhere in your code... try to identify the actual code that doesn't act as it should and put that here instead of all the code above...

Answer (score 0):

in your method `updateWithNMProduct`

```
-(void)updateWithNMProduct:(NMProduct *)nmProduct{

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
```

after the creation of your `context` local variable try adding this line...

```
NSManagedObject *newObject = [context insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product"];
```

Then use this instance to set entity attributes...

For example...

```
newObject.costPrice = [nmProduct.costPrice copy];
```